# convert an array to JSON in laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I have an array like:

```
    array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "2019-11-23"
    1 => 5
    2 => 5
    3 => 5
```

i would like to convert this to something like this (apart from the user):

```
    Collection {#940 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => User {#936 ▶}
    1 => User {#937 ▶}
    2 => User {#938 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I tryd json_encode() but that's didnt do the job...

Comment: please show me more code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this apply to your code?

```php
$myCollection = collect(['name' => 'Surc', 'age' => 30]);

$myCollection->toJson();
```